# How do compilers know when not to recompile?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

How do compilers know when it is not necessary to recompile certain parts of code  especially in larger projects?

---

For example, let's say in C++ we have two C++ files and two header files. The header files depend on one another. (They use the classes specified in each others files.)

Does a compiler always need to parse both header files, (and maybe C++ files for method implementation,) to obtain the class information in order to generate either of the two C++ files?

---

I always thought that when you run the compiler at the command prompt, it closes immediately after outputting the object files - so it would be impossible to cache the Abstract Syntax Trees or intermediate code. Do most C++ compilers know when a certain file doesn't need to output to an object file, and is therefore skipped?

Comment: This is typically the build system's job (e.g., make), not the compiler's.

Comment: This is the job of e.g. make with the help of a MakeFile

Comment: Normally it's the Make that does the checks, and it's quite complex to tell the make which files depend on which other files...

Comment: @xanatos It may be make, or it may be some other tool; the generic name, I think, is the build system.  And good build systems collaborate with the compiler, which "tells" them which headers are included each time.  (How well they collaborate depends, but I've gotten the VC++ compiler to tell GNU make about the dependencies.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the compilers I know compile every source file they're
told to.  Always.  And they generate a new version of the object
file for every source file they compile.

Only compiling what is necessary is a job generally left to the
build system (make or other).  Knowing which objects need to be
regenerated depend on what each source file includes, directly
or indirectly; most compilers have options to output this
information in some format, either on the fly or as a separate
invocation, and the build systems (the usable ones, at least)
use this information to determine dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

As said above, compilers will compiler every file that it is asked to compile. It is up to tools like make to decide what needs to be compiled.

In `make` one sets up rules. Each rule has a target, list of dependencies followed by the commands to run if those dependencies are not met. For example

```
target.o : target.c
    gcc -c -o target.o target.c
```

On most file systems, each file has a timestamp. If target.o has a newer timestamp than target.c (the rule dependency) then make does not run the gcc command below. This is because one firsts edits a source file and then compiles the source file into an object file.

If however the dependent source file is newer than the target, then we know the source file was edited after the compile took place and another compile is in order. `make` will therefore execute the build command for the rule.

It gets a lot more complex when rules are dependent on other rules but the same principle applies.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how they (don't) implement it (because many don't... Don't ask me why) but I'm quite sure it would be VERY easy. You save in the intermediate (obj) file the name and the hash of the source file and of every dependent file you are compiling, together with the compilation options that are being used, the hash of the compiler (or its internal version) and the compilation result (ok/error). Next time the user tries to recompile the file, the compiler checks if there is already the intermediate file, checks if all the hashes are the same, if the compilation options are the same and if the compiler is the same... If everything is the same, it gives the pre-saved error message and exits without doing anything.

The intermediate files would be a little bigger (probably some kb each).

Comment: I've never heard of a compiler or a build system doing it this way.  The usual build systems depend on compiler output to determine dependencies, and the time stamps on the file to determine which files actually need recompiling.

Comment: Sounds like `ccache` actually. Distributed builds are a bit harder than local builds, if only because of clock synchronization.